# Storing a variable within a service AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass a variable into a service that can be access from multiple states within my application. I have implemented a service and tried to pass a variable from a controller into the service so I can access it from another state as well as use it in other functions as well.

Here's my code:

Controller that get's input from html form and uses it in a function, I want to also store the value received from the input inside a service to used in other functions as well.

```
$scope.submit = function()
{
    var input = document.getElementById('userCode').value;
    var current;
    for(var i = 0; i < json.details.length; i++){
        current = json.details[i];
        if(current.pin == input){
        $state.go('LogInHome');
        $scope.Current = currentUser;
        $scope.Current.currentUser = input;
        }
    }
    console.log(current.currentUser);
}
```

Here is the service:

```
App.service('currentUser', function () 
{   
return{};
});
```

When I look at the console, i get "Undefined" where am I going wrong?

Comment: how do you mean? I am setting it to "input", so that it matches what was submitted from the html form.

Comment: that is because current contains data I request from an Ajax request. I do not want to mess with that at all, I just want to be able to take the input value and store it in a service

Comment: is it not case sensitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never Mind, I am an idiot. Rather than take this down and hide myself from the judging eyes of you all. I have decided to tell you all about my laughable mistake so people will have something to check. I forgot to inject the service. Many apologise for wasting people's time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.submit = function()
{
var input = document.getElementById('userCode').value;
var current;
for(var i = 0; i < json.details.length; i++){
    current = json.details[i];
    if(current.pin == input){
    $state.go('LogInHome');
    $scope.Current = currentUser;
    $scope.Current.currentUser = input;
    current = $scope.Current;
    }
}
console.log(current.currentUser);
}
```

This should give you the answer. Does it help?

Comment: current is in use elsewhere, I have tested by creating another variable ("var currentUserID = $scope.Current;"), to no avail.

Comment: i dont understand you

Comment: current is being used elsewhere in the script and i store a JSON object in it here; "current = json.details[i];" So I added a new variable in it's place and that still didn't work

Comment: But you are not inserting the value of `curentUser` in `current` you are inserting it in `$scope.Current`.. And `$scope.Current != current  `

Comment: i know, I'm trying to store it in the service "currentUser"

Comment: Please add a plunker then we can surely answer your question

Comment: i figured it out...added answer, i feel like such a tool.